# Add variables in Java like in PHP

Tags: java

Can i add variables (if that's right?) like you can do in PHP. like this:

```
<?php $title = 'just some title'; ?>
```

or:

```
<?php $ssid = session_id(); ?>
```

Is there someway i can do something like that in java?

Comment: Java is a strongly-typed language.

Comment: You can declare variables and assign values to them.  What have you tried and what didn't work?

Comment: i haven't tried anything, i just wondered if it was possible.

Comment: Are you really wasting our time asking if Java has variables? Even if you weren't aware that *it's a programming language*, you could have just googled 'java variables'.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

No as Java is a strongly-typed but if you want to declare a variable to reference to any other Class object you can use `Object` Class.

For example:

```
Object title = 'just some title';
```